# Replacing a DIV?

Tags: javascript

I need to replace a div with another div. Is there a way to place a div on top of another div and then just make that one transparent?

Comment: Which js framework are you working with?

Answer (score 11):

Easy. No need for a framework/library.

```
parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, oldNode);
```

If you only have the `newNode` and the `oldNode`:

```
oldNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, oldNode);
```

Comment: just keep in mind that `new` is an invalid variable identifier, so pick a better one for your use :)

Comment: Thanks. I just realised that when SO made it blue, so I'll change it now :P

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace the content of a div with the content of another div you can just go for

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = ...
```

Otherwise if you need to replace the entire div, you may want to use a parent div that contains the one you want to substitute and use the parent property.

If you need further help please add code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceChild()` ([see an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/replaceChildExample.htm))

Answer (score 0):

yes ofcourse there is a way to place a div on each other... you can do it by setting the z-index property of the  element.. this can b done by..
 and setting z-index of another higher than first one... then according to need you can give id to each div and make them visible or hidden.....

Answer (score 0):

Use this div property to play hide and seek game for the particular div. Copy and paste the whole code and try at your local computer.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .divStyle {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    }
    </style> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function displayDiv(){
        var divstyle = new String();
        divstyle = document.getElementById("div1").style.display;
        if(divstyle.toLowerCase()=="block" || divstyle == ""){
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";

        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" class="divStyle">Div One One One One 
    </div>
  <div id="div2" class="divStyle" style="display:none;">Div Two Two Two Two Two
    </div>   
    <center>
        <input type="button" value="display Div" onclick="displayDiv()" />
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use .replaceWith

Use modern vanilla JS! Way better/cleaner than before. Example:

```
target.replaceWith(element);
```